# How to convert a nested jsonObject to a hashMap with updated field names in java with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, hashmap

`UPDATE`: updated the codebase and now I am getting the key values pairs but there is some issue with the recursion logic while adding key|value pair. Need help with fixing this code.
`OLD ISSUE`:I have been trying to convert a `JSON` into a `HashMap` but as the `JSON` is a nested object I am unable to save the key name for the nested fields during recursion calls. Below is the ***updated*** sample code:

```
private HashMap<String,Object> addToMap(JsonNode jsonNode, HashMap<String, Object> map) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (jsonNode.isObject()) {
            ObjectNode objectNode = (ObjectNode) jsonNode;
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> iter = objectNode.fields();


            while (iter.hasNext()) {

                Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = iter.next();
                parentKey=entry.getKey();
                //set key from the mapperLookup.

                map.put(parentKey,  addToMap(entry.getValue(),new HashMap<String,Object>()));

            }
        } else if (jsonNode.isArray()) {
            ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) jsonNode;
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayNode.size(); i++) {
                //set key from the mapperLookup.
                map.put(parentKey,  addToMap(arrayNode.get(i),new HashMap<String,Object>()));

            }

        } else if (jsonNode.isValueNode()) {


            ValueNode valueNode = (ValueNode) jsonNode;
            //set key from the mapperLookup.
            map.put(parentKey, valueNode.asText());
        }
        return map;

    }
```

**Sample input:**

```
{
"S_name":"xyz",
"K_id":"12233",

"N_dum":[{"K_id":"dfff"},{"S_nam":"dfgg"}]


}
```

**expected output:**

```
{S_name=xyz,
 K_id=12233,
 N_dum={K_id=dfff,S_nam=dfgg}
}
```

**Current output:**

```
{S_name={S_name=xyz}, K_id={K_id=12233}, N_dum={N_dum={K_id={K_id=dfff}}, K_id={S_nam={S_nam=dfgg}}}}
```

Improvements would be helpful.
As I need to do some transformation with the key names that's why I am following this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using ObjectMapper like following:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> dataRaw = null;
dataRaw = mapper.readValue(rawValues, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
```

which rawValues is a json string.

Comment: As I need to make changes to the key names I can't go with this as this would give me a hashMap equivalent to the json object. I need to create a hashmap with different key names so iterating over the json and adding updated key to a new hashmap would be better.